# Парсить XML с необязательным элементом и со Схемой

Tags: xml, java, dom

Имеется простая `XMLSchema`. В ней описан необязательный элемент. Т.е. `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"`.  
Как мне распарсить XML, созданный по этой схеме?
Парсинг делаю примерно по такой схеме:

- получаю NodeList корневого элемента;
- вызываю метод item() у этого NodeList.

Но как мне быть с необязательным элементом? Ведь, вызвав номер, выходящий за пределы, я получу `NullPointerException`.

Comment: А чем length не нравится?

Comment: непонял. поясните пожалуйста. я вторые сутки у компа. непонимаю :)

Comment: @argamidon, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NodeList.length
```

Comment: Я так и сделал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, стоит применить блок try{} catch.
Была похожая проблема при вычитке елементов с xml на с++, пришлось описать вычитку проблемных нодов в блок try{}.

Comment: Вот этого я очень не хочу. Это же нелаконично :)